# Differences & Similarities between I2C & SPI Analyzers

Tags: i2c, spi

I am learning about I2C and SPI analyzers and want to know about the differences between the two. What is the difference between their functionality and what are the similarities in these analyzers, if any?

Comment: Before learning about the analyzers (whatever they are..), learn about the protocols themselves. then you will come up with the differences yourself.

Comment: I know about protocols but there is no information on the web about their analyzers and what could be the similarities and differences between them

Comment: If you know about the protocols, what the analyzers needs to do follows from that.  Perhaps you should spend more time thinking over what you have read about the protocols, or doing some hands-on work with them.  You can also examine the codebases of available open source analyzers that do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functional difference between them. They're just logic analyzers that are optimized for one protocol or the other. They might have implementation differences such as header types, pin counts, or voltage/current tolerances, but those are just a result of the manufacturer targeting one protocol or another. They may also have firmware or client-side software that helps the user decipher protocol control signals and data, as opposed to a normal logic analyzer that just displays signals and timing diagrams.

In fact, you'll find many devices out there that can analyze both, such as the [Beagle I2C/SPI Analyzer](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-i2cspi/).

The similarities are too numerous to count because they're just different flavors of the same thing. The differences are superficial.

Comment: There are definitely *functional* differences, but the valid point you are trying to make is that this is usually accomplished in *software*.  Generally the only reason you'd end up with something that could do one but not the other is if the vendor was deeply in a "license capabilities" mindset or if there literally were not enough pins for SPI.   But yes, there are lots of extremely inexpensive solutions that can do both.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think we may be working from different definitions of "functional difference." I meant that they essentially do the same thing, in that the functions and tools they provide to the end user are largely the same, and that the differences that do exist are mostly just implementation details. I've made a small edit to try to clarify this.